# Geoserver freemarker template language check file link

Tags: freemarker, geoserver

Right now I am developing webGIS by using Geoserver and I am using Get Feature Info. For the Get Feature Info, I want to show in the pop up the image of the feature (photo image from field) but not all the features already have the photos so I need to check if the photo is exist or not by link. How am I supposed to do that by using FTL? Here is some of my code by using FTL.

```
            <#assign image = "http://10.1.160.59:8082/geoserver/www/project/images/photo/img_"+feature["site"].value+"_"+feature["drillholes"].value+".jpg">
            <#if image?has_content>
                <tr><td>${"image"}</td> <td><img src=${"http://10.1.160.59:8082/geoserver/www/project/images/photo/img_"}${feature["site"].value}${"_"}${feature["drillholes"].value}${".jpg"} height="200" width="250" style="border-width:1;border-style:solid"/> </td></tr>
            </#if>
            <#if !image?has_content>
                <tr><td>${"image"}</td> <td><img src=${"http://10.1.160.59:8082/geoserver/www/project/images/photo/No_Image.jpg"} height="200" width="250" style="border-width:1;border-style:solid"/> </td></tr>
            </#if>
```

So basically I am supposed to check if the image exists or not. If exists I will use the image link but if not I will use the No Image link.

Comment: Not related to the question, but things like `<td>${"image"}</td>` are equivalent with `<td>image</td>`, so `${"..."}` is hardly ever useful. Also, instead of the second `</#if><#If !firstCondition>` you could just write `<#else>`.

Comment: As of the question, I know nothing about Geoserver, but maybe detecting the issue should be the task of the browser. I mean it does detect it inevitably (HTTP 404), and then you can handle that situation with JavaScript/CSS inside the browser.